# Dialect not known to support REF_CURSOR parameters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, plsql

In Spring Boot app I'm doing request to oracle db with StoredProcedureQuery

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("checkTest");

        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(4, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

        query.setParameter(2, dto.getIdentity());
        query.setParameter(3, dto.getSourceIp());
        query.setParameter(4, dto.getSource()); query.execute();
```

[image: It is my plsql response]

It is my plsql response

But in my code i get error with
`QueryException: Dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect] not known to support REF_CURSOR parameters`

Comment: Are you using Oracle? Why don't you use org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect instead of org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect?

Comment: yes, i'm using oracle

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a proper dialect depending on the database that you are working with.

In this case of Hibernate 5.4, try:

- *org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10g* for Oracle 10 g or,
- *org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect* for Oracle 12c.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/

On the other hand, if you used this stored procedure on MySQL, it won't work because the MySQL driver does not support REFCURSOR parameters.